# Join Position Leaderboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to create a top command that shows the first 10 Members that joined on the server. Unfortunately I found only one code for Javascript. But since I'm programming my Discordbot with Python, I need help.

Comment: If your use-case is small you can achieve this by iterating through `Guild.members` and picking the users (10) who have the oldest join dates (datetime) `member.joined_at`.
To make things easier you can sort `Guild.members` based on join date first and then take the last 10 elements.

Comment: Did my solution answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64931661/13228935 - if so, please mark it as accepted to close this one off. If not, please provide your code and addition info so that the community can better assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to get all of the users into a list, sorted by their join date ascending, you can simply use list splicing; excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/13228935)

```
your_list[:10]
```

This example will return index 0-9 inclusive of **your_list**